# read input from stdin but not have it echo

Tags: bash, echo, stdin

I'm needing to use a script to add some characters to the front end of existing interface descriptions on switches - in this case Cisco interfaces.  I have a working script to read "show interface descriptions" from a file called "in".  However, I'd like to do this with /dev/stdin instead so I don't have to create the input file first.

```
 echo "config t"
 echo " "

  while read -r a b c d e; do
  echo "interface" "$a"
  echo "desc" "-hst>" "$e"
  echo "exit"
  echo " "
  done < /dev/stdin

 echo "end"
 exit
```

The problem is that the input from stdin also echos back out on each corrected interface.  I want this to be an output that can be put right back into the switch, so this is not ideal.

When using the input file script I get this as the output:

```
config t

 interface Gi1/0/1
 desc -hst> to user access port
 exit

 interface Gi1/0/2
 etc....
```

Which is exactly what I want.

But when using stdin I get this:

```
Gi1/0/1                        down           down     ge to user access port   <<<---- this is the input 
interface Gi1/0/1
desc -hst> to user access port
exit

Gi1/0/2                        up             up       ge to user access port   <<<---- this is the input
interface Gi1/0/2
etc....
```

I don't want the 2 input lines to be within the block.
I'm thinking that perhaps I need to echo to stdout instead.

Thoughts?
Thank you.

Comment: There's no need to use `< /dev/stdin`, that's the default input source.

Comment: You don't need the input redirection, whose sole purpose is to change standard input for the command from something other than the standard input inherited from the shell.

Comment: Use `read -s` to read without terminal echoing.

Comment: -s worked perfectly!  Thank you for the quick and accurate response!

Comment: @ShaneBishop I was trying to find a duplicate. I couldn't, but I hoped someone else would.